# Write to elasticsearch from spark is very slow

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-spark

I am processing a text file and writing transformed rows from a Spark application to elastic search as bellow

```
input.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
      .mode(SaveMode.Append)
      .option("es.resource", "{date}/" + dir).save()
```

This runs very slow and takes around 8 minutes to write 287.9 MB / 1513789 records.
[image]

How can I tune spark and elasticsearch settings to make it faster given that network latency will always be there.

I am using spark in local mode and have 16 cores and 64GB RAM. 
My elasticsearch cluster has one master and 3 data nodes with 16 cores and 64GB each.

I am reading text file as below

```
 val readOptions: Map[String, String] = Map("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace" -> "true",
  "ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace" -> "true",
  "inferSchema" -> "false",
  "header" -> "false",
  "delimiter" -> "\t",
  "comment" -> "#",
  "mode" -> "PERMISSIVE")
```

....

```
val input = sqlContext.read.options(readOptions).csv(inputFile.getAbsolutePath)
```

Comment: How many partition there is in input ? Is spark sharing resources with elasticsearch ? you can always change the default write bulk size, i believe it's 500 by default.

Comment: Actually I am creating dataframe using csv plugin `val input = sqlContext.read.options(readOptions).csv(inputFile.getAbsolutePath)`. I don't know How many partitions it creates. Spark is not sharing resources with elasticsearch.

Comment: How big is your file ? Is it partitioned or is it one big bloc ?

Comment: It is 70MB gz file with of network access logs. It's one single un partitioned file

Comment: And I imagine that you inferSchema within your readOptions which will leads to scan the data twice. Can you print the output of df.rdd.getNumPartitions ?

Comment: No I am not inferring any schema. I have updated question about how I am reading file. df.rdd.getNumPartitions = 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, Let's start with what's happening in your application. Apache Spark is reading 1 (not so big) `csv` file which is compressed. Thus first spark will spend time decompressing data and scan it before writing it in `elasticsearch`.

This will create a `Dataset`/`DataFrame` **with one partition** (confirmed by the result of your `df.rdd.getNumPartitions` mentioned in the comments).

One straight-forward solution would be to `repartition` your data on read and cache it, before writing it to `elasticsearch`. Now I'm not sure what your data looks like, so deciding the number of partitions is subject of benchmark from your side.

```
val input = sqlContext.read.options(readOptions)
                      .csv(inputFile.getAbsolutePath)
                      .repartition(100) // 100 is just an example
                      .cache
```

I'm not sure how much will be the benefit on your application, because I believe there might be other bottlenecks (network IO, disk type for ES).

**PS:** I ought converting csv to parquet files before building ETL over them. There is real gain of performance here. (personal opinion and benchmarks)

Another possible optimization would be to tweak the `es.batch.size.entries` setting for the elasticsearch-spark connector. The default value is `1000`.

You need to be careful when setting this parameter because you might overload elasticsearch. I strongly advice you take a look at the available configurations [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/configuration.html).

I hope this helps !